# jquery synchron fadeout and fadeto with differnt elements

Tags: jquery, synchronization, fade

i try to get a solution for following problem.

synchron fadeout and fadeTo with different elements.

the page behavior should be like this
- page load
- content hidden
- menu shown
- content fadeIn and menu fadeTo opacity 0.0

my snippset of code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".content_main").hide();
        $(".content_main").fadeIn(8000);
        $(".header > ul").ajaxSend(function(){this.fadeTo("8000", 0.0)});
});
```

but this isn't synchron, any hint ??

Comment: okay I solved the problem.
using the jquery plugin "jQuery FxQueues 2.0.3" with this two commands
$(".headerul").animate({opacity: 0.0}, {duration: 3000,queue:"first",scope: "global"});
  $(".content_main").animate({opacity: 1.0}, {duration: 3000, queue:"first", scope: "global"});

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".content_main").hide();
        $(".content_main").fadeIn(8000, function () {
            $(".header > ul").ajaxSend(function(){this.fadeTo("8000", 0.0)});
        });
});
```

You basically specify a callback for fadeIn, so when it finishes, it calls that function.
I'm not sure this is exactly what you want, but you get the idea.

Comment: thx, but i try the callback function befor, there the problem is that the callback is call after the fadeIn